# InStr inside a Left()

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port, serial-communication

I copied the code below directly from the communication manual of a sensor to check the BCC.

```
strSTX_Command = Left(strReceiveStr, (InStr(1, strReceiveStr, Chr(3)) - 1))
```

The next error is displayed :

"Error  BC32016 'Public Overloads Property Left As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed.    "

I am not sure what is wrong with this code. Thanks for any helpful information.

Comment: Left() is a legacy VB function name.  It has a popular name, good odds that this code is inside a Form class.  It also has a Left property and it wins.  You'll have to spell the full name to avoid the ambiguity, VB.NET is happy when you write Strings.Left().  Most programmers prefer the System.String methods over the legacy functions.

Comment: It works, thanks. So, when using a Form class, it is risky to use the bare Left() function name? Interesting.